# How to extract part of the line from the file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

file.txt:

```
hello:"hello"; my love; my world:"my is world"
Questions<<my:"475832">> data-addon="652256"---my lover :"987654321";;;Questions
heart!Questions
```

but I want to take number after a string "data-addon="

example:

```
652256
```

Is possible with command `awk`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easier to use `grep`:

```
grep -Po 'data-addon="\K[^"]*' file
```

or to store output in the variable:

```
var=$(grep -Po 'data-addon="\K[^"]*' file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Save your sample data as `manuel.txt` and run:

```
awk '/data-addon/ {gsub(/^.*data-addon="/,"");gsub(/".*/,"");print}' manuel.txt
```

to store the result in a variable:

```
myvar=$(awk '/data-addon/ {gsub(/^.*data-addon="/,"") ; gsub(/".*/,"") ; print}' manuel.txt)
```

This would be easier in sed:

```
sed -n '/data-addon/ { s/^.*data-addon="// ; s/".*// p}' manuel.txt 
myvar=$(sed -n '/data-addon/ { s/^.*data-addon="// ; s/".*// p}' manuel.txt)
```

Comment: anonymous downvoter: if you're going to downvote, at least have the courtesy to explain why.

Answer (score 0):

In that sort of scenario, I use `awk`, splitting words around quotes and spaces & loop through fields:

```
awk -F'[ "]*' \
'
{
  for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
  {
    if ($i == "data-addon=")
    {
      print $(i+1)
      exit
    }
  }
}
' file.txt
```

HTH

Answer (score -1):

The following should do what you want:

```
cat file.txt | awk -F"data-addon=" '{print $2}' | awk -F\" '{print $2}' | awk NF
```

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: cat file.txt | awk -F"data-addon=" '{print $2}' | awk -F\" '{print $2}' | awk NF
id=$2
echo "ecccco---$id"  result not save in variable..i'm wrong.. i'm newbie..sorry..

Comment: It works as you want it to if you have the file.txt with the text you mentioned. Try copying the text that you posted in file.txt and run the command that I posted. You'll get the number as the output.

The command is specific to this scenario only.

Comment: if you wanted the result stored in a variable, you should have mentioned that fact in your question.